# Displaying PostGIS database data

Tags: postgis, google-maps, php, geomoose

I'm a beginner in this field and tried to display the PostGIS database data in localhost. I used select query in my code, so the table got displayed.  I want to display the geographical points in a map overlay or in GeoMoose. I'm attaching the code which I used to display the table. Can anyone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<?php
  class assets {
    public $gid;
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $main;
    public $asset_name;
    public $assetname;
    public $geom;

    //Database Variables

    public $connection;
    public function __construct()     {
        $this->connection = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgis user=postgres password=1234") or print("cant connect");
    }
    public function __destruct() { 
    }
    public function create() {
    }
    public function read() {
          $result = pg_query($this->connection, "SELECT gid,id, name, main,asset_name,assetname,geom FROM assets");
          if (!$result) {
              echo "An error occured.\n";
              exit;
          } else {
          echo "<table border=1>";
          echo "<tr><td>gID</td><td>ID</td><td>Name</td>
                    <td>Main</td>     <td>asset_name</td>      <td>assetname</td>      <td>geom</td></tr>";

                   while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result))  {
                          echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td valign=top>".$row[0]."</td>";
                          echo "<td valign=top>".$row[1]."</td>";
                          echo "<td valign=top>".$row[2]."</td>";
                              echo "<td valign=top>".$row[3]."</td>";
                                  echo "<td valign=top>".$row[4]."</td>";
                                      echo "<td valign=top>".$row[5]."</td>";
                                      echo "<td valign=top>".$row[6]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                   }

          echo "</table>";
          } 

    pg_close($this->connection);
    }
    public function update(){
    }
    public function delete(){
    }
}
$myAssets = new assets();
$myAssets->read();
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for attaching code in this way.I'm new to this and so dont know where to attach the code

Comment: You need to do a few things ot get an answer. 1. format your code so it is readable, in an indented structure so people can read it. Secondly, state the language you are working in and ad it as a tag. there isa formatting help button immediatly above th ebox where you entered you question, and please check out the help at the top of the page.

Comment: the language used is php

Comment: What's with the weird spacing in your prose and code? Your random use or misuse of the space bar, in this and your other questions, won't win you many friends.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to represent binary geometry as a string so you can easily pass it to the map. See [PostGIS geometry outputs section](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs) of the docs. You might want to look into GeoJSON a bit.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm trying to plot the points in geomoose

Comment: @user43112 - Is that an acceptance of, or a rebuttal to, the answer?

Comment: Actually i didnt get the result with that explanation.Because the answer gave only an idea about postgis geometry conversion and the query which i asked was not that.but the answer given for this question helped me for developing further.so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some extra spaces in your SQL call, just delete them and try again. Try to get extra information with `console.log()` and firebug or some other debugging tools. The better the verbose mode you use, the easier the way you solve your issue.